# Using different serialisers to send/receive data in Ember/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I've got an Ember CLI app using a Ruby on Rails API backend. I initially built this using a REST API, and am trying to migrate it to use JSONAPI.

To send data from Rails to Ember this is simple - I have just updated the ActiveModelSerializers gem that I was already using, and have updated the adapter and serialiser in the Ember app to be something like:

```
export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter;

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer;
```

The problem is that it is a lot of work to rewrite my whole Rails app to respond to a new data format, so I would like to stick with the REST adapter/serializer when sending data from Ember to Rails (at least in the short term). I am not sure how to do this. I was thinking of something like this:

```
export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  serialize(snapshot, options){
    return DS.RESTSerializer.serialize(snapshot, options);
  }
});
```

This doesn't work. Has anyone done this? Is there a good way to do it?

Many thanks

Comment: `DS.RESTSerializer` is a class, you would need to instantiate it with `.create()`.

Comment: Thanks @Lux. Still doesn't work though - I'm now getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lookup' of undefined`

Comment: Maybe you should look it up from the DI container?

Comment: Any chance of some example code? I'm not quite sure how to do that, am a bit out of my depth with this problem! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically `DS.RESTSerializer` is a `class`, but `serialize` is an instance method. So you have to `.create()` the serializer:

```
let instance = DS.RESTSerializer.create().serialize(...arguments)
```

However this *will not work* because the Serializer does access the DI container, and so expects to be initialized by the container. You can manually inject the owner like this:

```
DS.RESTSerializer.create(Ember.getOwner(this).ownerInjection()).serialize(...arguments);
```

Comment: Thanks. This gives the error `_ember.default.getOwner is not a function`

Comment: So you are not on current ember versions right? This has [changed recently](http://emberjs.com/blog/2016/01/15/ember-2-3-released.html#toc_introducing-owners-and-deprecating-containers). There is a [polyfill](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-getowner-polyfill) for older versions you could use.

Comment: Yes sorry, should have mentioned - upgrading the API is all part of moving on from 1.13. This still isn't working I'm afraid, with the polyfill I'm now getting the new error `ext.js:173 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'modelFor' of undefined`